# Android OutOfMemory

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview, android-memory

What is my Problem (KISS)?
After showing the 3rd Image in Detail my App crashes cause OutOfMemory

Background information about my App:
I made an **offline** Supermarket. All products are shown in a ListView.
All Images I use are stored as String (Uri from every Image) in a sqlite Database by SugarORM.
The ListView element got a ArrayAdapter where the Information for each Item in the ListView is set.
Like this:

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.productimage);
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
       imageView.setImageURI(productList.get(position).getPictureUri());
       handler.removeCallbacks(this);
     }
 });
```

My Intention was, to load the Images in the Background to Click on it, even before the Image is loaded (But it did'nt work for me :/ The Image is Shown, but I cant click on any other View Element while Loading the Image).
The "getPictureUri" gets the URI from the Picture that the Admin has choosen for the product with the following Code:

```
Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(pickPhoto,1);
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

I extend only from "**AppCompatActivity**" (Needed for Toolbar). Meaning of this: I don't use "**Activity**" even once.

Could anyone give me a good advice, how to clear the cached Images (I think this might be the Problem) and besides, maybe one of you got the Time to help me with my "Image Async Loading while you are able to move freely in your app" Problem.

Comment: About freezing: as the documentation for setImageUri says: "This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead."  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)

Comment: But proper image loading is very hard to implement. I would suggest using library for this, Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide is excellent even with default setup. It may even solve your problem with out of memory exception.

Comment: @josef.adamcik 1st Comment: Thanks for the advice, I may have a look at it now. 2nd Comment: I want to use my App only Offline. I dont think, that glide offers me the possibility (just assuming that it only works with online URL's) to load images from URI, which are saved at the mobile phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using setImageUri() is rather intensive on memory, especially when trying to load large bitmaps from a local resource. Instead, use tried and true solutions like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for any/all image loading tasks. The libraries will work offline, can definitely load images from URIs pointing to a local resource and would most likely solve all your memory issues with image loading.

Comment: Nice, it was really easy to use and saved sooo much Memory. Thanks.